# How to update multiple fields in Firebase Web?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code where I want to update some simple values in my Firebase database using the JavaScript, Web SDK.

However, it doesn't run/update my database. What's wrong here?

```
    var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('feeds').child(selectedFeed).child('audio');
    var uid = dbRef.push().key;

    var data = {
      "downloadURL": uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL,
      "fileName": file.name,
      "timeStamp": selectedDateUnix
    };

    var updates = {};
    updates["mostRecentKey"] = uid;
    updates[uid] = data;

    dbRef.update(updates).then(function(){
      //success
      alert("Successfully Uploaded. This is now available to be listened to by your users.");

    }).catch(function(error){
      //failure
      alert(error.message);

    });
```

Comment: Do either of the alerts fire?

Comment: Nope, they don't.

Comment: Is this code running at all? I did a local test with this code and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, downloadURL and timeStamp and causing it to fail as they are var references as their values. If I replace them with strings for example, it works. Why would this be? Am I formatting it poorly?

Comment: Ok, turns out I needed to cast the data with `Number()` and `String()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it doesn't ever specify in the Firebase docs and actually I felt indicated it wasn't required; You MUST cast your data. For example:

This does not work. Directly accessing the variable.

```
var myNum = 10;
var data = {};
data["myNum"] = myNum;
```

This does work, but doesn't allow a dynamic use of a `var`.

```
var data = {};
data["myNum"] = 10;
```

Finally, this works and was my solution using a variable reference. Cast your data.

```
var myNum = 10;
var data = {};
data["myNum"] = Number(myNum);
```